# How can I create a function with null arguments?

Tags: r, function, apply, lapply, mapply

I have three vectors, which I need to apply to a template, replace something, and create new files. this is the function:

```
multx<-function(){
  readLines(Template) %>%
    gsub(pattern = "stx", replace = stimearray) %>% #Replaces the start time
    gsub(pattern = "etx", replace = etimearray) %>% #Replaces the end time
    write.table(., paste0("ds/", iNames), #Writes out a file for every batch
              row.names=F, col.names=F, quote = F)
}

x <- mapply(multx)
```

This is the part that creates the global variables that are also used in other functions:

```
runStart <- lubridate::ymd_hm(startDate) #Start date 
stimearray <- runStart + months(0:(nMonths-1)) 
etimearray <- runStart + months(1:nMonths) - lubridate::dhours(1)
```

But in this case, `stimearray`, `etimearray`, and `iNames` are `vectors` that are already available in the global environment from previous calculations.

How can I create an empty argument function in order the create the batch of files?

Or, is there another way to do it?

### Data

Template

```
c("", "\"! ***********************************************************************************************************************\"", 
"\"simulStart              stx     ! (01) simulation start time -- must be in single quotes\"", 
"\"simulFinsh              etx      ! (02) simulation end time -- must be in single quotes\"", 
"\"\"", "\"! ***********************************************************************************************************************\""
)
```

## dput(stimearray)

```
structure(c(1475280000, 1477958400, 1480550400, 1483228800, 1485907200, 
1488326400, 1491004800, 1493596800, 1496275200, 1498867200, 1501545600, 
1504224000, 1506816000, 1509494400, 1512086400, 1514764800, 1517443200, 
1519862400, 1522540800, 1525132800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC")
```

## dput(etimearray)

```
structure(c(1477954800, 1480546800, 1483225200, 1485903600, 1488322800, 
1491001200, 1493593200, 1496271600, 1498863600, 1501542000, 1504220400, 
1506812400, 1509490800, 1512082800, 1514761200, 1517439600, 1519858800, 
1522537200, 1525129200, 1527807600), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"))
```

Comment: I don't think it is advisable to use global environment variables in a custom function... Can't you just add the corresponding arguments? If they were passed from another function call, then you should use `...` I guess

Comment: Calling `mapply` on a function without supplying any parameters to iterate over just returns `list()`, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: @DamianoFantini What if those variables were also used in other functions? Do I add the calculation to every function? Is there another way to organize this? The calculations are not long. But those variables are being used in 3-4 functions.

Comment: @alistaire Could you please explain what I should do. I didn't get it.,

Comment: @DamianoFantini Do you mean pass off the variables as arguments even though the variables are already available globally?

Comment: `Map` iterates a function across parameters in parallel, e.g. `Map(seq, from = c(1, 11), to = c(5, 15))`. `mapply` does the same thing, but tries to simplify the resulting list into a matrix or vector like `sapply`. One of these may make sense in this case, but it's hard to say without sample data.

Comment: @alistaire I have attached the data. Could you please take a look again?/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Map`, the multivariate version of `lapply`, to do this:

```r
template <- c("", "\"! ***********************************************************************************************************************\"", 
              "\"simulStart              stx     ! (01) simulation start time -- must be in single quotes\"", 
              "\"simulFinsh              etx      ! (02) simulation end time -- must be in single quotes\"", 
              "\"\"", "\"! ***********************************************************************************************************************\"")

stime <- structure(c(1475280000, 1477958400, 1480550400, 1483228800, 1485907200, 1488326400, 1491004800, 1493596800, 1496275200, 1498867200, 1501545600, 1504224000, 1506816000, 1509494400, 1512086400, 1514764800, 1517443200, 1519862400, 1522540800, 1525132800), 
                   class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")

etime <- structure(c(1477954800, 1480546800, 1483225200, 1485903600, 1488322800, 1491001200, 1493593200, 1496271600, 1498863600, 1501542000, 1504220400, 1506812400, 1509490800, 1512082800, 1514761200, 1517439600, 1519858800, 1522537200, 1525129200, 1527807600), 
                   tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))

dir.create("ds")

file_data <- Map(function(start, end, name){
        filled_template <- gsub("stx", start, template, fixed = TRUE)
        filled_template <- gsub("etx", end, filled_template, fixed = TRUE)
        writeLines(filled_template, file.path("ds", name))
        filled_template    # return vector written to file
    }, 
    start = stime,
    end = etime,
    name = paste0("file-", as.integer(stime), ".txt")
)

file_data[1:2]
#> [[1]]
#> [1] ""                                                                                                                             
#> [2] "\"! ***********************************************************************************************************************\""
#> [3] "\"simulStart              2016-10-01     ! (01) simulation start time -- must be in single quotes\""                          
#> [4] "\"simulFinsh              2016-10-31 23:00:00      ! (02) simulation end time -- must be in single quotes\""                  
#> [5] "\"\""                                                                                                                         
#> [6] "\"! ***********************************************************************************************************************\""
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] ""                                                                                                                             
#> [2] "\"! ***********************************************************************************************************************\""
#> [3] "\"simulStart              2016-11-01     ! (01) simulation start time -- must be in single quotes\""                          
#> [4] "\"simulFinsh              2016-11-30 23:00:00      ! (02) simulation end time -- must be in single quotes\""                  
#> [5] "\"\""                                                                                                                         
#> [6] "\"! ***********************************************************************************************************************\""
```

Note that the default print method for POSIXct times that are at midnight omits the time part. If you want it to print, call `format` on the time, e.g. `format(start, "%F %T")`.

Comment: Thanks! That's awesome. A quick question. How would I go about inserting the dates as '2016-11-30 23:00:00', i.e. with the commas. Is that something I should do inside the startTime dataframe for example? Or can I do something using format?

Comment: You mean single quotes? `paste0("'", start, "'")`

Comment: Silly me, Thanks a lot!